# RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression - apache 2.4.9

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am getting this error in Apache error log and my website is unable to open in Apache 2.4.9

```
RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression '^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\\s+]+)$'
```

but I am able to open the website in earlier version of apache, please help what is wrong with apache 2.4.9?

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)$ ?x=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([\w+\s-]+)$ ?x=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Hyphen needs to be at the start or end in a character class to avoid escaping.